# Multiple choice dropdown as thymleaf attribute

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

is possible to do drop down with multiple choice?
I am trying to make form with drop down and when I add "multiple" as attribute:

```
 <select multiple th:field="*{cars}">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
 </select><br/>
```

it looks like:
[image: dropdown with multiple choice]

but I would like to dropdown like this and use is as th:field:

[image: dropdown without multiple choice]

Comment: I don't believe that what you want to do is possible (maybe with some custom coding it would be possible). But even if it were possible, I think it would make for a poor user experience because the user would only be able to see one of the selected values when the drop-down is not being used. Almost all users would probably assume that there is only one such selected value anyway, since that's how these types of drop-down work, normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so finnaly I had to add some scripts and css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select  th:field="*{cars}" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Role</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

After add that I have working dropdown with checkboxes and multiple choice